# How to split a string and create new array objects from it?

Tags: php

I have

```
$myId = $_POST['varPostId'];
```

The value of `$myId` is `242,428`

So I first give it a white space after the comma:

```
$myId = str_replace(',',', ', $myId);
```

Then I explode it and create an `array`:

```
$parts = explode('.', $myId);
$parts = array($parts);
```

Then i do:

```
print_r($myId);
```

And I get:

```
Array ( [0] => 248, 242 )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the explode is correct? You are exploding around `.`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I am not actually, I am asking

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: why a downvote???

Comment: i don't understand. you're doing `$myId = array($myId)`, but when do you use `$parts`??

Comment: got the answer, thanks

Comment: @LilianBarraud true, update the question, had simplified wrongly and forgot to change the var names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Don't do lengthy code.***

Simply go for `explode()` with `$myId` variable itself.

```
$parts = explode(',', $myId);

print_r($parts);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/979497

Answer (score 2):

You're doing

```
$myId = str_replace(',',', ', $myId);
```

So here `$myId` contains `248, 242`

Then you're asking for

```
$myId = array($myId);
```

So as an output you have your ID in an array hense the

```
Array ( [0] => 248, 242 )
```

What you have to do is

```
$parts = explode(',', $myId);

print_r($parts);
```

or

```
$myId = explode(',', $myId);

print_r($myId);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to get an array with the two numbers then you can simply do it like:

```
$arrayWithNumbers = explode(',', $myId);
```

What's wrong with your code?
I see two problems within your code:

You're exploding the string by '.', so your string will stay as it is.
And then you're using

```
array($myId);
```

which will create an array, which will only contain your string.